# NSubstitute ForPartsOf mock all methods except one?

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

Using NSubstitute, it's possible to mock only specific methods using `Substitute.ForPartsOf<T>()`. But this will by default call the real methods unless you specifically configure a method to be mocked, e.g. `mySubstitute.Configure().MyMethod().Returns(/*whatever*/)`.

I would like to do the reverse: create a substitute that mocks all methods by default, and then specify one particular method to make a real call.

Is there a nice clean way to do that?

The best approach I've been able to come up with is (untested):

```
MyClass realObj = new MyClass();
var subst = Substitute.For<MyClass>();
subst.MyMethod().Returns(realObj.MyMethod());
```

I guess I'm looking for a shortcut to doing this:

```
var subst = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();
// Mock all methods except MyMethod:
subst.Configure().MyOtherMethod().Returns(/*whatever*/)
subst.Configure().MyThirdMethod().Returns(/*whatever*/)
// ...
subst.Configure().MyLastMethod().Returns(/*whatever*/)
```

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think my suggested approach would work. The `realObj.MyMethod()` call will make any internal calls to the real methods of `realObj`, rather than call the ones on `subst`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt-in to calling the base implementation of a normal sub.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual int MyMethod() => 42;
    public virtual int MyMethod1() => 1;
    public virtual int MyMethod2() => 2;
    public virtual int MyMethod3() => 3;
}


[Fact]
public void Sample() {
    var sub = Substitute.For<MyClass>();

    sub.When(x => x.MyMethod()).CallBase();            

    // Returns from base:
    Assert.Equal(42, sub.MyMethod());
    // Other methods mocked (return default value for int):
    Assert.Equal(0, sub.MyMethod1());
    Assert.Equal(0, sub.MyMethod2());
    Assert.Equal(0, sub.MyMethod3());
}
```

Remember the disclaimer that all the methods on `MyClass` should be `virtual` for NSubstitute to be able to work with them. :)

Comment: Right, of course! Thanks! Re virtual, I've already learned that it's not enough that a method implements an interface method. In fact, that's irrelevant; instead, being virtual is relevant. :-)

Comment: @KjellRilbe Here's an explanation for the `virtual`/interface requirement: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/ The members need to be overridable so they can be replaced with substitute implementations.

Comment: Thanks, but I already understand it. I just didn't think properly. Ugh... Might be helpful to others though, so thanks for adding that comment.